# Uploading photos to server with node.js using android java, volley

Tags: java, android, node.js, server, android-volley

I am creating a chat page for users, everyone should be able to open their own chat and add chat photos, but somehow I cannot upload the photos I received from the user's gallery to the server.(only 1 photo will be uploaded at a time)

## **Endpoint**

```js
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9);
        const ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
        cb(null, uniqueSuffix + ext);
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('image');

app.post('/api/chat/upload', (req, res) => {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
            console.error('Multer error:', err);
            return res.status(500).json({ message: 'An error occurred during image upload' });
        } else if (err) {
            console.error('Error:', err);
            return res.status(500).json({ message: 'An error occurred during image upload' });
        }

        const imageUrl = req.file.path;
        const realImageUrl = `https://projechats.com/api/chat${imageUrl.replace('uploads/', 'images/')}`;
        res.status(200).json({ imageUrl: realImageUrl });
    });
});
```

*other express, link and port codes are available in endpoint
*

*code where I take a photo from the user's gallery, crop it and round it*

## **Activity code**

```
public class FragmentCreateChat extends Fragment {

    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final int CROP_IMAGE_REQUEST = 2;

    private ImageView selectImage, camIcon;
    private Button createChatButton;
    private Uri imageUri;

    String groupname, groupdes;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.mainColor));

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_chat, container, false);
        createChatButton = view.findViewById(R.id.create_chat_button);
        selectImage = view.findViewById(R.id.select_image);
        camIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.camera_icon);
        camIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        selectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openGallery();
            }
        });

        createChatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText createChatTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.create_chat_title);
                EditText createChatDes = view.findViewById(R.id.create_chat_des);

                groupname = createChatTitle.getText().toString().trim();
                groupdes = createChatDes.getText().toString().trim();

                if (groupname.isEmpty() || groupdes.isEmpty() || imageUri == null || groupname.matches("^\\s*$") || groupdes.matches("^\\s*$")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please fill all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                } else if (groupname.length() < 6 || groupdes.length() < 20) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Chat name: at least 6 characters, description: at least 20 characters. should be", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                } else {
                    //sunucuya ve mysqle kayıt
                    uploadImageToServer(((BitmapDrawable) selectImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            imageUri = data.getData();
            cropImage(imageUri);
        } else if (requestCode == CROP_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = data.getParcelableExtra("data");
            selectImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            camIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            setCircularImage();
        }
    }

    private void openGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    private void cropImage(Uri imageUri) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intent.setDataAndType(imageUri, "image/*");
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CROP_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    private void setCircularImage() {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) selectImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        int desiredSizeDp = 60;
        float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int desiredSizePx = (int) (desiredSizeDp * scale + 0.5f);

        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, desiredSizePx, desiredSizePx, false);
        Bitmap circularBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(desiredSizePx, desiredSizePx, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(circularBitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        RectF rectF = new RectF(0, 0, desiredSizePx, desiredSizePx);
        float radius = desiredSizePx / 2f;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, radius, radius, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode(android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBitmap, null, rectF, paint);

        selectImage.setImageBitmap(circularBitmap);
    }

    private void createNewChat(String groupphoto, String groupname, String groupdes) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.MyUserid), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String adminid = sharedPreferences.getString("userid", "");

        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Successfully created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        };

        Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (error.networkResponse != null) {
                    if (error.networkResponse.statusCode == 400) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invalid or missing fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (error.networkResponse.statusCode == 409) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Group already exists with this name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "An error occurred, please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Could not connect to server. Please check your Internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };

        VolleyCreateNewChat createNewChat = new VolleyCreateNewChat(adminid, groupphoto, groupname, groupdes, responseListener, errorListener);
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(createNewChat);
    }

    private void uploadImageToServer(Bitmap imageBitmap) {
        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                String imageUrl = response; // Örnek bir URL
                createNewChat(imageUrl, groupname, groupdes);
            }
        };

        Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "An error occurred while uploading the image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        VolleyUploadImageRequest uploadImageRequest = new VolleyUploadImageRequest(imageBitmap, responseListener, errorListener);
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(uploadImageRequest);
    }
}
```

---

```java
public class VolleyUploadImageRequest extends Request<String> {
    private static final String URL = "https://projechats.com/api/chat/upload"; // Sunucu URL'sini buraya yerleştirin
    private static final String BOUNDARY = "*****";
    private static final String LINE_FEED = "\r\n";
    private static final String TWO_HYPHENS = "--";

    private Bitmap imageBitmap;
    private Response.Listener<String> responseListener;

    public VolleyUploadImageRequest(Bitmap imageBitmap, Response.Listener<String> responseListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.POST, URL, errorListener);
        this.imageBitmap = imageBitmap;
        this.responseListener = responseListener;
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + BOUNDARY;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);

        try {
            // Resim dosyasının başlangıcını işaret et
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(TWO_HYPHENS + BOUNDARY + LINE_FEED);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\"image.jpg\"" + LINE_FEED);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(LINE_FEED);

            // Resmi byte dizisine dönüştür
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byte[] imageBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

            // Byte dizisini çıktı akışına yaz
            dataOutputStream.write(imageBytes);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(LINE_FEED);

            // Resim dosyasının sonunu işaret et
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(TWO_HYPHENS + BOUNDARY + TWO_HYPHENS + LINE_FEED);
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String responseBody = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(responseBody, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Response.error(new VolleyError(e));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(String response) {
        responseListener.onResponse(response);
    }
}
```

How can I save the user selected photo to the server and get the url to view the photo later in the app?
my current codes are giving 500 error i checked everything on server but still not working

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: all code will help to solve 1 endpoint, 1 activity and the class used in it